# Windows 10 Anniversary; suddenly won't sleep, even manually

Tags: windows-10, sleep, windows-10-v1607

I can't figure out what changed between Friday and Sunday, but my PC suddenly won't sleep.  Even if I put it to sleep manually, it goes to sleep, but wakes up about two seconds later.

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_1142&SUBSYS_85BF1043&REV_00\4&312afb2e&0&0028
    Friendly Name:
    Description: ASMedia USB3.0 eXtensible Host Controller
    Manufacturer: ASMedia Technology Inc
```

There is no option in the hardware manager to "Allow this device to wake the computer". My drivers from Asus are up to date, and I have no devices plugged into the USB 3.0 rear ports. I do have a 3 port + SD card reader connected to the internal 20-pin, but that has been there for months with no issues.

Any ideas why I can't get the PC to sleep?

System:

- Asus M5A97 R2.0
- AMD FX 8320
- XFX Radeon HD 7850

Comment: Judging by the cmd output, this probably isn't the case, but I know when this happened to me on Windows 7 it was because I was booting using GRUB. Sleep doesn't seem to like GRUB for some reason. When I changed to the Windows bootloader, it worked.